# why does jpa query the same column multiple times when using a one to many relationship?

Tags: java, jpa

i have some jpa code that persists a user, who has a set of permissions. the table in sql is two columns, the user_id and the permission. however when i try to read that user, the generated sql looks off.  specifically, the two columns are selected multiple times. here is some relevant code...

Entity Classes...

```
@Entity
@Table(name="users")
public class User implements Storable{

    @OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name="user_id",referencedColumnName="user_id")
    private Set<Permission> permissions;

}

@Entity
@Table(name="permissions")
public class Permission implements Storable{

    @EmbeddedId
    PermissionPK id;

    @MapsId("userId")
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="user_id")
    User user;  
}

@Embeddable
class PermissionPK implements Serializable{
    @Column(name="user_id")
    int userId;
    @Column(name="permission")
    String type;
```

}

code that queries...

```
User u = em.find(User.class, 262);
```

Here is the query that is generated for finding the permissions...

```
select
    permission0_.user_id as user2_8_1_,
    permission0_.permission as permissi1_3_1_,
    permission0_.user_id as user2_3_1_,
    permission0_.permission as permissi1_3_0_,
    permission0_.user_id as user2_3_0_ 
from
    permissions permission0_ 
where
    permission0_.user_id=?
```

i cannot figure out for the life of me why the user_id column is selected 3 times and the permission column twice. it ends up being ok for me since i store the permissions in a set and thus the duplicates are removed. but i would like to know why it does this so that i can address future problems where i might not be storing in a set

Comment: Why would this query generate duplicates? Side notes: if you used an autogenerated, single-column ID, you wouldn't have the problem. And it would be easier to have the mapping right. Your mapping is wrong: The OneToMany association should use the mappedBy attribute, to be marked as the inverse side of the ManyToOne in Permission. And it shouldn't be annotated with JoinColumn.

Comment: according to the logs, it appeared to me that it was making duplicates. youre right though, when i tested it more fully, the result set has the right number of rows. i would still like to know the reasoning as to why jpa selects the same column multiple times. even after i fixed the mappedBy attribute it is still resulting in the same query. and the id for the user class is autogenerated. i just didnt include it because i didnt think it was relevant.

Comment: The Permission entity should have an auto-generated, single-column ID. In fact, all your entities should. It would be more efficient, easier to code, easier to map, no need for PK classes with potentially buggy equals and hashCodes, clean URLs with a single parameter to refer to a given permission by ID...

Comment: thanks. i didnt realize using the embedded ids cause so many problems. switching to a single column id did the trick